# Aux cable option to car stereo

Tags: stereo

I have this old car stereo and would like to add aux cable option to this player. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Use a mini FM transmitter to couple your aux device up to the FM radio.

Comment: Yes it's possible. How easy depends on how it's built and we don't know that.

Comment: Maybe i'm old but something that says "MP3" and "WMA" on it doesn't sound like it can be that old.

Comment: @PeterGreen mp3 stereos have been around since the nineties. 20 years is old.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [service manual](http://diagramasde.com/diagramas/otros2/KDC-MP228.pdf) for your KDC-MP3029, the only real option you have to hack in an aux cord or connector is less than stellar option of soldering to the CD Player's audio output. On the CD board, there is a test point for Lch (Blue), Rch (Red), and Audio Gnd (Orange), right by Connector CN1.

[image]

Or you could try on the main board, by CN1, and C1 and C2.

[image]

This is a very hacky type hack. You'll need to burn a cd to have no audio, a 90 minute cd of silence or whatever for the audio to be heard from your aux cable. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgqa0pbc650 for an example.

Alternatively, you could try to hack in the external CD/Aux connector J2 in, but all the support parts, resistors, diodes, are not populated on your player.

Comment: @david it would have to be very quiet science. ;D

Answer (score 2):

<s>I googled for the manual and it seems that stereo has a connector on the back intended for a CD changer which can also be used as an aux input. Googling for "kenwood aux input cable" seems to find numberous sources for such cables.</s>

Seems I was wrong in the OPs particular case, the manual mentions the CD changer connector but the manual covers multiple models and it seems it's not fitted on the model the OP has (see Passerby's comments and answer).

Comment: From the manual, the MP3029 does not have a B/Accessory connector.

Comment: And confirmed it on the service manual's detailed BOM.